# Importing data surrounded by Square brackets

Tags: import

I have a big one line data file with a list of integers which are in the following format:

```
[[1 4 5 6 2] [9 8 7 4 7] [....]],[[...] .....[...]],.....]]
```

I have been trying Import but what I get is

```
{{[[1,4,5,6,2],[9,8,7,4,7],[....]],[[...] .....[...]],.....]]}}
```

The problem is that I can not replace the "[" and "]" by "{" and "}" respectively.

How I could a list of lists with brackets?

Thanks regards

Comment: I guess something like `ImportString["[[1 4 5 6 2] [9 8 7 4 7] [10 3 1 0 5]],[[3 0 9 1 7] [5 6 11 1 7] [3 0 2 0 1]]", "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> {" "}, 
 "IgnoreEmptyLines" -> True, "LineSeparators" -> {",", "[", "]"}]`?

Comment: Hi, I can not copy-paste the content of the file into `ImportString` command of your example because there are mores than 300 000 integers. Also, this example gives {{1,4,5,6,2},{ }, [9 8 7 4 7] .

Comment: import the whole thing as string then, `ToExpression[StringReplace[instring, {" " -> ",", "[" -> "{", "]" -> "}"}]]`    (You may need an extra pair of `{ }` around the whole thing )  Is this matlab output by the way?

Comment: The idea is to use `Import[filename, "Table", options]` on your end, where you make the necessary replacements.

Comment: I have tested the two alternatives work fine. Thank you very much @J.M and

Comment: and thanks to  and @george2079.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ToExpression[
StringReplace["[[1 4 5 6 2] [9 8 7 4 7]]", {" " -> ",", "[" -> "{", "]" -> "}"}]]
(* {{1, 4, 5, 6, 2}, {9, 8, 7, 4, 7}} *)
```

Comment: i just realized george2079 wrote the same answer in the comments

Answer (score 5):

This is what you after?

```
string="[[1 4 5 6 2] [9 8 7 4 7] [10 3 1 0 5]],[[3 0 9 1 7] [5 6 11 1 7] [3 0 2 0 1]]";
ImportString[StringReplace[#,Whitespace->","],"RawJSON"]&/@StringSplit[string,","]
```

> {{{1,4,5,6,2},{9,8,7,4,7},{10,3,1,0,5}},{{3,0,9,1,7},{5,6,11,1,7},{3,0,2,0,1}}}

Comment: +1, and a suggestion: it'll be more robust if you replace `" "` with `Whitespace`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Good suggestion,I have updated that.Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You could use something like this if your data is not too large:

```
terp = Interpreter[
  DelimitedSequence[
   DelimitedSequence["Number", {"[", Whitespace, "]"}],
   {"[", Whitespace, "]"}
   ]
  ]

terp["[[1 2] [3 4]]"]
(* {{1, 2}, {3, 4}} *)
```

You can add another layer of `DelimitedSequence` if you have several such expressions separated by commas.

Unfortunately, this method of parsing is quite slow.